# node.js http response data terminated when data size is large

Tags: php, node.js, http

I am using nodejs and sending http post request to server. On server side I am running php. My server is returning correct data around 9KB but data in nodejs client is terminated. It works fine if data is less than 6KB. Following is my code

```
        var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            Console.log('Cloud Resp:', d);
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(d);
        });
    });
```

My print  Console.log('Cloud Resp:', d) prints data up to 8KB only. Can someone please help me to understand if this limit is imposed by nodejs or something else and how can I increase the limit

Comment: Are you really using body-parser? Seems your project is not a express based app server instead it is using https module to request data from your PHP server. If possible please share more code for information. I guess the result is chunked into several pieces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your data is chunked during transfering **PHP server ---> Node server**

- I assume you are using native `https` module to request from Node side (Correct me if I am wrong)

So in `data` event you need to concat the chunk. But you parse it only in `end` event. If you parse in `data` event it will show you error for `JSON.parse()` because of incomplete data

Here is the sample code, it works with a 500kb data as I tested. Basically native node does not has data limitation in code level.

```
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "c16db448-d912-4ce8-823a-db6c51e09878.mock.pstmn.io"
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = '';

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.length)
    chunks += chunk;
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    const object = JSON.parse(chunks)
    console.log(object.length)
    console.log(Buffer.byteLength(chunks, 'utf8') / 1024 + " kbytes");
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked flawless. Yes I was using HTTPS. Thank you so much Yue You. You saved my day

Comment: Glad that I can help

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you are using **body-parser** too right? That is causing an issue.

Body Parser Allows data up to certain limit (100kB I guess) by default.

To increase the limits go to:
**node_modules**>**body-parser**>**lib**>**types**>**json.js**

look for the following line:

```
var limit = typeof opts.limit !== 'number'
? bytes.parse(opts.limit || '100kb')
: opts.limit
```

replace the *100* in *100kB* with the limit you want to impose in your application. This should fix it.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to change node_modules:
set the *limit* option when you declare the bodyparser variable.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
bodyParser.json({limit: *your limit in bytes*});
```

This works only in case of JSON parsing. you can set limit parameter to raw, text, urlencoded formats too similarly (check documentation link below).

See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions).

Thank You  @iofjuupasli for suggesting that there could be a better way.

Comment: Never modify code in node_modules. Especially in such case, when you can config with arguments

Comment: Is there any way to change in the application itself? We do not have control over node.js installation as we are running it in Lambda function provided by Amazon to integrate with Alexa.

Comment: Is this really a body-parser issue? Did not see any related information from anwser

Comment: Yes it is a body parser issue. It limits the incoming HTTP request size. If the size exceeds the limit (100kB default), it throws an error: Payload Too Large. it usually occurs when you are playing with files or have huge base64 being parsed.

Comment: I don't agree. The code in the answer only shows native Node Api `https.request` and  `JSON.parse`. There is no place mentioned about he has used body-parser as middle-ware

Comment: Please note Console.log('Cloud Resp:', d); only prints partial data when data size is 9-10KB. So problem is before JSON.parse is called. We have copy pasted the partial print log in notepad and size of the notepad file 8039 bytes. So it terminated data more than this size.

Comment: @Gailu Body-parser is just a 3rd party library but what I can see you are just using native node api to request and parse data. See my answer below. Hope that helps,

Comment: Also I tried to set bodyParser as suggested but getting error

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

bodyParser.json({limit: 10000000});

Error I get
Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:9:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

Comment: @Gailu If you are not using bodyParser. This answer is not related to your question. See my answer below. Hope it helps

Comment: @GobindDeepSingh just a tip - saying "I need points lol" is not the best way to get reputation.